# zsh prompt and hostname

Tags: shell, zsh, hostname, zshrc

I use the following prompt in .zshrc:

```
PROMPT="%{$fg[magenta]%}%n%{$reset_color%}@%{$fg[blue]%}%m %{$fg[yellow]%}%1~ %{$reset_color%}%# "
```

When I open terminal I see this prompt:

```
zoltan@zoltan-Macbook-Pro ~ %
```

Is it possible to drop the text "zoltan" in the hostname? I would like to make it look like this:

```
zoltan@Macbook-Pro ~ %
```

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps change the hostname of your system? `%m` is "The hostname up to the first '.'" An alternative might be to define another variable with the value you want, and reference that instead of `%m`...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's a bit of a mess, but you can pretend the `%m` is a parameter and use parameter expansion to strip the `zoltan` from the host name:

```
PROMPT="...${${(%):-%m}#1} ..."
```

A little explanation. First, you create a "parameter" expansion that doesn't actually have a parameter name; it just uses the text you provide as the "value":

```
${:-%m}
```

Next, add the `%` expansion flag so that any prompt escapes found in the value are processed.

```
${(%):-%m}
```

Finally, next it in a final expansion that uses the `#` operator to remove a prefix from the string:

```
${${(%):-%m}#zoltan-}
```

You can tame your prompt a bit by building up piece by piece (and use `zsh`'s prompt escapes to handle the color changes, rather than embedding terminal control sequences explicitly).

```
PROMPT="%F{magenta}%n%f"  # Magenta user name
PROMPT+="@"
PROMPT+="%F{blue}${${(%):-%m}#zoltan-}%f" # Blue host name, minus zoltan
PROMPT+=" "
PROMPT+="%F{yellow}%1~ %f" # Yellow working directory
PROMPT+=" %# "
```

Comment: Thanks for colors syntaxis, I finished one line prompt: (no oh-my-zsh):  
```export PROMPT="%F{magenta}%n%f@%F{blue}${${(%):-%m}#zoltan-}%f %F{yellow}%1~ %F{white}"```

Comment: I took your answer and ran with it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/66462684/117471 I included many links to documentation. Thanks for the inspiration! ☮️❤️

Answer (score 16):

If you're using OhMyZsh, this is one line to add at the bottom of you .zshrc if you want the user and hostname in your PS1/PROMPT :

```
export PROMPT='%(!.%{%F{yellow}%}.)$USER@%{$fg[white]%}%M ${ret_status} %{$fg[cyan]%}%c%{$reset_color%} $(git_prompt_info)'
```

Enjoy ;)

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I had PS1 set in .zshrc. Look for '%m' - this corresponds to the hostname that you see in the prompt. Replace it what you want. Let me replace '%m' with CUSTOM.

---

**OLD**

[image]

```
autoload -U colors && colors
PS1="%{$fg[green]%}%n%{$reset_color%}@%{$fg[cyan]%}%m %{$fg[yellow]%}%~ %{$reset_color%}%% "
```

---

**NEW**

[image]

```
autoload -U colors && colors
PS1="%{$fg[green]%}%n%{$reset_color%}@%{$fg[cyan]%}CUSTOM %{$fg[yellow]%}%~ %{$reset_color%}%% "
```

Answer (score 3):

I stumbled upon this question and the [wonderfully informative answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30204002/117471) from @chepner inspired me to remove the `.local` from the `%M` ([**fully qualified** machine hostname](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html#:%7E:text=The%20full%20machine%20hostname)) in my own universal prompt.

In their case, they did:

```
${${(%):-%m}#zoltan-}
```

In my case, I did:

```
${${(%):-%M}%.local}
```

#### NOTE:

In shell [substring removal](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html#:%7E:text=Substring%20Removal)

- `#` means "trim from the left"
- `%` means "trim from the right"

You can remember which is which because `#` and `%` are on the left and right of `$` which is the char you use for [`${parameter_substitution)`](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html#PARAMSUBREF).