# How to change the prompt in oh my zsh and add hostname to it?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, prompt, oh-my-zsh

My oh my zsh prompt reads something like:

```
tenant-application git:(beta-4-1)
```

I want it to read something like:

```
homestead tenant-application git:(beta-4-1)
```

Or something similar where I can understand the hostname of the machine

When I do `echo $PROMPT`, it says

```
${ret_status} %{$fg[cyan]%}%c%{$reset_color%} $(git_prompt_info)
```

I tried:

```
export PROMPT=${ret_status} ${hostname} %{$fg[cyan]%}%c%{$reset_color%} $(git_prompt_info)
```

But the error said:

```
zsh: not an identifier: %{^[[36m%}%c%{^[[00m%}
```

What am I doing wrong and how to make the right thing permanent?

Comment: I think you might find the right answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30199068/zsh-prompt-and-hostname

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add quotes to avoid immediate expansion of your expressions. Further the hostname up to the first dot can be inserted by using `%m` or the full hostname with `%M` (see http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html)

So this command should work:

```
export PROMPT='${ret_status} %m %{$fg[cyan]%}%c%{$reset_color%} $(git_prompt_info)'
```

To make this permanent you can just add this line to your `.zshrc` file in your home directory.