# How I can remove the question-marks characters from "zsh shell" terminal line?

Tags: terminal, themes, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I am using zsh shell on mac terminal, I was playing with oh my zsh theme to jazz a little bit and I have noticed that there are question marks characters around the directory I am in, so my question is how I can remove them? also is there any way to short cut -MacBook-Pro to MBP?
[image]

Comment: I can try to help, but I'm not a oh-my-zsh user. The "?" could be utf-8 characters you don't have. What replies `echo $LANG` ? If you don't use git you can disable this. Check out [this question for the hostname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30199068/zsh-prompt-and-hostname), or search your config files for PS1 or PROMPT.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is probably caused by fonts.

I have same problem with my fish shell with tide theme, and I'm struggling now.
However, some question-marks began to display normally in my terminal(still remain some question-marks..), so I hope this will be helpful for you.

Here I share some solutions that may be a hint for you.

1. Install the Nerd Fonts
   https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts
2. Change the font setting from terminal preference.

- If you use iTerm2,

  - check 'Use built-in Powerline glyphs'.
  - select a font 'for Powerline'. (If you can't see any font for Powerline, you need to install fonts for powerline by googling.)

[image]

- If you use normal macos terminal,

  - change the font to any 'for Powerline'

[image]

Comment: When I choose a font something including "~ nerd ~", finally it display correctly!